# Get first letter from C string

Tags: c

I have a program in C which is basically a contact book, and I've already done all the functionalities (add contact, delete etc) but I also have to implement a way to search for contacts by the initial letter (the user type any letter, and if they exist contacts that start with that letter they should be displayed) but I'm not getting the first letter of the vector of names to do this... My attempt to do this is in the SearchContactsByFirstLetter function...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
    char number[MAX_LENGTH];
    int bd;
    int bdm;
} ContactBook;

void ListContacts(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;

    printf("\n List of contacts: \n");
    printf("\t---------------------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d = birthday: %2d month %2d\t name: %s \t number: %s\n", i + 1, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm, c[i]->name, c[i]->number);
    }
}

int addContacts(ContactBook **c, int quant, int size)
{
    if (quant < size)
    {
        ContactBook *new = malloc(sizeof(ContactBook));
        printf("\nenter contact name: ");
        scanf("%49[^\n]", new->name);
        printf("\nenter number: ");
        scanf("%s", new->number);
        printf("\nenter the birthday ");
        scanf("%d", &new->bd);
        printf("\n enter the month birthday: ");
        scanf("%d", &new->bdm);
        c[quant] = new;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n full list.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int deleteContact(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int id;

    ListContacts(c, quant);

    printf("\n\t Enter the id you want to delete: \n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    id--;
    if (id >= 0 && id < quant)
    {
        free(c[id]);
        if (id < quant - 1)
        {
            c[id] = c[quant - 1];
        }
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t wrong code;\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void birthdays(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    printf(" os aniversariantes do mês são: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        if (tm.tm_mon + 1 == c[i]->bdm)

        {

            printf("\t%d = birthday: %2d month %2d\t name: %s \t number: %s\n", i + 1, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm, c[i]->name, c[i]->number);
        }
    }
}

void SearchContactByFirstLetter(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;
    char searchedName[2];

    printf("\n Search a letter: \n");
    scanf("%s", searchedName);
    getchar();

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(searchedName, c[i]->name[0]) == 0)
        {
            printf("\t\nname: %s, \nnumber: %s, \nbirthday: %d \nmonth birthday %d \t\n", c[i]->name, c[i]->number, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm);
        }
    }
}

void SearchContact(ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    int i;
    char searchedName[30];

    printf("\n Search name: \n");
    scanf("%s", searchedName);
    getchar();

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(searchedName, c[i]->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("\t\nname: %s, \nnumber: %s, \nbirthday: %d \nmonth birthday %d \t\n", c[i]->name, c[i]->number, c[i]->bd, c[i]->bdm);
        }
    }
}

void saveBinary(char arquivo[], ContactBook **c, int quant)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(arquivo, "wb");
    int i;

    if (file)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
            fwrite(c[i], sizeof(ContactBook), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
        printf("erro");
}

int readBinaryArq(char arquivo[], ContactBook **c)
{
    int quant = 0;
    ContactBook *new = malloc(sizeof(ContactBook));
    FILE *file = fopen(arquivo, "rb");

    if (file)
    {
        while (fread(new, sizeof(ContactBook), 1, file))
        {
            c[quant] = new;
            quant++;
            new = malloc(sizeof(ContactBook));
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
        printf("\nerro");
    return quant;
}

int main()
{

    ContactBook *contacts[50];
    int option, size = 50, quant = 0;
    char arq2[] = ("agenda.dat");
    quant = readBinaryArq(arq2, contacts);

    do
    {
        printf(" \n\t0 - exit\n\t1 - register contact\n\t2 - Remove contact\n\t3- List contacts\n\t4- Search contact\n\t5 - ver aniversariantes do mês\n\t6-Pesquisar por inicial\n ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        getchar();

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            quant += addContacts(contacts, quant, size);
            break;
        case 2:
            quant += deleteContact(contacts, quant);
            break;
        case 3:
            ListContacts(contacts, quant);
            break;

        case 4:
            SearchContact(contacts, quant);
            break;
        case 5:
            birthdays(contacts, quant);
            break;
        }
        saveBinary(arq2, contacts, quant);

    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see a question in there. And you've given us a lot of code that seems to have nothing to do with getting the first letter from a C string.

Comment: If you only want to check a single letter, don't use strcmp. Just do `if(searchedName[0] == c[i]->name[0])`

Comment: Also, always pay attention to and fix all compiler warnings. It should have warned you to the fact that the second parameter given to `strcmp` is not the expected type.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (strcmp(searchedName, c[i]->name[0]) == 0)
```

That should be:

```
    if (searchedName[0] == c[i]->name[0])
```

But you probably shouldn't read in a string in the first place if you only want to read a single character.